# Need specific information on NTRIP protocol

Tags: network-protocols

I am developing an application that use NTRIP protocol. I need the packet that is sent by  the NTRIP client to the server. The application I am building uses the HTTP stream. The client will connect to this application and send data using HTTP from which I will extract certain information and process it.
I need the sample data that the client will send.

Answer (score 2):

Old thread, but... If you want to see how the data conversation goes, you could get a copy of GNSS Internet Radio and connect it to a NTRIP Caster while running a packet sniffer to capture the data.

If you're just looking for a NTRIP Client, I wrote one in VB.Net that is open source. You could use that to see how the connection handshaking works.
http://lefebure.com/software/

Comment: Thanks Lance, I will check out the NTRIP client. I saw that you also have NTRIP Caster on your web page. Is this a proxy service that sits between the clients and the real caster?

Comment: No, the caster isn't a proxy to another caster. In NTRIP there are 3 pieces - a server (reads data from a serial port), a caster (receives data from one server, sends to many clients), and a client (gets data from a caster, sends to a GPS receiver). The NTRIP Caster I wrote is a caster and server in one app, plus it can accept streams from other servers.